# Checking for existing records with MySQLi prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I have written a script to insert an email address in a table but I want to check if the address already exists. So I begin with a prepared statement:

```
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `signups` WHERE `signups_email`= ? ");
$statement->bind_param('s',$email);
$statement->execute();

if($statement->num_rows < 1){ 
     $statement->close(); //Free up the SQL result
    //do the inserting code
} else {
    echo "Email already exists";
}
```

Trouble is, `($statement->num_rows < 1)` seems to always return true, even when I know there is an email in the database. I.e. it doesn't figure out that the address is already in the database.

My connection etc is fine as the `//do the inserting code` bit works fine.

Comment: Alternatively, if you only have to check for that one column, you could use a `UNIQUE` index on that column, and avoid an unnecessary `SELECT` query.

Comment: But wouldn't that throw up an error when I try to insert an entry that already exists? My method makes error handling on the front end very easy.

Comment: You could do `INSERT IGNORE` which wouldn't raise an error even if there already was such an entry, and then check for the number of rows inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation for [mysqli_num_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php).

> Returns the number of rows in the result set. The use of
> mysqli_stmt_num_rows() depends on whether or not you used
> mysqli_stmt_store_result() to buffer the entire result set in the
> statement handle.
>
> If you use mysqli_stmt_store_result(), mysqli_stmt_num_rows() may be
> called immediately.

It looks like you need to call store_result() before you can check the number of rows.

Answer (score -1):

Your statement fails if the email already exists in the DB. the `if()` should be

```
if ($statement->num_rows == 0) {
   ... email does not exist, insert it
} else {
   ... at least one record with that email exists
}
```

Comment: I don't see how "equals to zero" makes any difference from "less than one" in this case.

Comment: @pilsetnieks I was about to ask the exact same thing